# Slidesjs pagination image is always hidden but can on the function if mouse hovers over

Tags: javascript, css

Using Magento Go due to other users lack of developer knowledge.

Slidesjs has been added relatively simply and works except for the pagination, the image has been stored in the media storage system, but I cant access it from the css code added to the theme in the customise section.

code is below:

```
.pagination li a {
display:block;
width:12px;
height:0;
padding-top:12px;
/*background-image: url(’../HomePage/Icons/pagination.png');*/
background-position:0 0;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

The code is currently edited out simply due when its enabled the slider itself stops working, however the pagination image doesnt appear anyway.

But enough digressing, from the css code in the theme customise section, can a media storage image be accessed and if so how is it done? I have tried various permutations all result in no image, almost as if it is hidden behind something, however I can access the background.png from the same CSS snippet placed into theme editor > customiser > CSS.

Also has anyone solved the pagination hidden issue with Magento Go and Slidesjs?

After reviewing more documentation I noticed this in the user guide:

background:url(../css_editor_images/imageName.gif) no-repeat }

which means the above should work but doesnt for some reason... will keep trying the workaround.

Comment: You may be best off just setting the CSS value embedded in the template itself rather than in the style sheet (or setting it with jQuery or something in the template).

Comment: I didnt want to change the overall code of slidejs too much, so was wanting to work with the CSS I had with minimal changes, but if that is the only way round it?

Answer (score 1):

This could just have occurred when you pasted it into your post, but check out your single quotes. Non utf-8 characters like curly quotes give me no end of headaches.

Meaning that you probably want...

```
/*background-image: url('../HomePage/Icons/pagination.png');*/
```

versus

```
/*background-image: url(’../HomePage/Icons/pagination.png');*/
```

Comment: Ah sorry I forgot to update this one from a few days ago when I solved it...

Really embarrassing solution, but I somehow missed the Css image button (swear it was not there last time I looked) which solves the problem quite easily.

Everything is now working as it was intended.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Magento Go, but as long as you can find the template that generates the markup for your slides, you should have the code that initializes slides.js, something such as:

```
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#slides").slides();
        });
    </script>
```

You can include a pagination class to hook into with the additional option:

```
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slides({
        paginationClass: 'pagination'
      });
    });
```

Then, inside the template (instead of in the stylesheet file) you can update the background image:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .pagination {
        background: url(path/to/your/image.jpg) no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I will give this method a try as a workaround, will report back when checked.

Comment: Did you find an answer here? Please mark it as solution.